# Is there a shorter way of writing 'if a > b: a = b' in python?

Tags: python

Can you shorten the following example?

`if file_size_download > file_size: file_size_download = file_size`

It looks quite clumsy to me.

Comment: I don't know about python but usually you can do something like like `a = Min(a,b)`. Might lead to different results for calculations involving `NaN`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
a = min(a, b)
```

This is short and concise.

Answer (score 0):

As a more generic answer:

```
a = b if a < b else a
```

The previous answer works fine in this particular case, however, this can be of use in cases where it's not just a `<` comparison.